# древовидная структура данных

Tags: c++, список, структуры-данных, динамические-массивы

С помощью каких инструментов можно реализовать древовидную структуру? Иерархическая модель компании: допустим есть 1 начальник, 3 менеджера и 7 работников. Можно ли создать связанный список из 3 ячеек, но такой, чтобы в каждом элементе было соответствующее количество необходимых ячеек, что то типа массива динамического?

Comment: Открываем книгу Кормена "Алгоритмы" и ищем деревья. Единственное что подскажу, так это использовать вместо самих объектов указатели на них, чтобы легче и быстрее можно было менять и добавлять связи. Собственно на SO решают проблемы с кодом, а у вас нет даже его намека.

Comment: а что значит SO?

Comment: StackOverflow :)

Comment: Да хоть `vector<list>>` :), но непонятно, при чем тут древовидная структура. Как мне кажется - плясать нужно от функциональности, того, что вы хотите с ними делать. Например, все они могут быть производными от какого-то класса "сотрудник", а предприятие - быть коллекцией сотрудников или что-то вроде того...

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Company{
std::string Chief_name;
std::string  manager_names[3];
std::string  working_names[7];    
};

int main()
{    
    std::list<Company> lst;
    // вводите в lst ваши обьекты Company
    return 0;
}
```